# I'm trying to return a inserted row from the stored procedure using getEntityManager in symfony but receiving response as false

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, symfony4

Here is the stored procedure used in MsSql server

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[StudentCreate]
(
    @name VARCHAR(250),
    @age INT
)
AS

INSERT INTO Student (name, age, state, country) VALUES (@name, @age, 'TN', 'India')

SELECT state, country FROM Student WHERE student_id=@@identity
```

---

Here is the symfony5 code I'm trying to fetch the data from the stored procedure

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection();
$sql = '{CALL StudentCreate(?, ?)}';
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $name, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $age, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
return $result;
```

but it returns false

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance...